# Encoding problems in gvim window title

Tags: windows, vim, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm running gVim 7.4 on a Windows 10 machine.

- The system version is single-language-cyrillic (can not change this).
- The language for non-unicode programs is set to russian.
- _vimrc contains the following commands: `set langmenu=en_US.UTF-8` `set encoding=utf-8` `set guifont=Lucida_Console:h14` (this font has cyrillic glyphs)

However, the window title and the output of several commands contains some gibberish. My guess is that gvim tries to print something in russian but fails.

An example of such behavior (note the window title, the output, and the invitation for the next command in the end):
[image: example]

What is the best course of action here? What should I put into _vimrc (or tweak in my OS) to make this gibberish readable? Any advice would be helpful.

Full listing of my _vimrc:

```
set langmenu=en_US.UTF-8

filetype plugin on
set shellslash
filetype indent on
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
set encoding=utf-8
set backspace+=start
syntax enable
if has('gui_running')
set guifont=Lucida_Console:h14
set background=light
set guioptions-=T
else
set background=dark 
endif
colorscheme solarized
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf,aux'
set nu
set wrap
set linebreak
set nolist
set formatoptions+=l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is only about messages in gVim, not about displaying content of your file or a menu, you can try to put this line in your _vimrc

```
language messages ru_RU.UTF-8
```

---

Edit: Unfortunately, this doesn't work because there is no ru_RU.UTF-8 folder presented in gVim (it would need to be created, more about it [here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/183222/)). So it is possible to change to English only with

```
language messages en_US.UTF-8
```

[`:h language`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/mlang.txt.html#multilang-messages)
[`:h win32-gettext`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/mlang.txt.html#win32-gettext)

Comment: Actually, in my case this line does not change anything in vim's behavior. However, `language messages en_US.UTF-8` does the trick - vim becomes 100% english.